# value of 1.3 is becoming 1.40000001 in parsefloat

Tags: angular, typescript, numbers, parsefloat

I am reading some values from mongodb and then i have some options that increase the price. there are 2 type of options single and multiple. if single all the operations run smoothly. if multiple when i am reading the value (eg "1.3" ) parse float returns 1.4000001
the code that does this is the following :

```
 this.item.productPrice = parseFloat(this.item.productPrice) - 
   parseFloat(a.price);
```

and

```
          this.item.productPrice = parseFloat(this.item.productPrice) + parseFloat(a.price);
```

using debugger at the beginning of the line item.productPrice is 1.3 but after the parsing it becomes 1.4000001 and adds the a.price

the full codeblock

```
//this one takes the selection and adds it to selectedparams array
  selected(ev: any) {
    debugger;
    const a = JSON.parse(ev);
    if (a.multiple) {
      if (Array.isArray(this.selectedparams[a.paramName])) {
        const va = !a.value;
        const index = this.objectinArray(this.selectedparams[a.paramName], {
          option: a.option,
          price: a.price,
          value: va
        });
        if (index !== -1) {
          this.item.productPrice = parseFloat(this.item.productPrice) - parseFloat(a.price);
          this.selectedparams[a.paramName].splice(index, 1);
          this.zone.run(() => {});
        } else {
          this.selectedparams[a.paramName].push({ option: a.option, price: a.price, value: a.value });
          this.item.productPrice = parseFloat(this.item.productPrice) + parseFloat(a.price);
          this.zone.run(() => {});
        }
      } else {
        this.selectedparams[a.paramName] = [];
        this.selectedparams[a.paramName].push({ option: a.option, price: a.price, value: a.value });
        this.item.productPrice = this.item.productPrice + parseFloat(a.price);
        console.log('hereeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee', this.item.productPrice);
        this.zone.run(() => {});
      }

    } else {
      this.selectedparams[a.paramName] = { selected: a.selected, price: a.price };
    }
    this.calcPrice();
  }

//this one dows the calculation after adding
  calcPrice() {
    const keys = Object.keys(this.selectedparams);
    console.log(this.item);
    let newprice = this.item.productPrice;
    keys.forEach(el => {
      if (Array.isArray(this.selectedparams[el])) {
        this.selectedparams[el].forEach((i: any) => {
          newprice = newprice + parseFloat(i.price);
        });
      } else {
        newprice = newprice + parseFloat(this.selectedparams[el].price);
      }
    });
    this.showPrice = newprice;
  }
```

Comment: What is the value of `this.item.productPrice` before adding the `parseFloat(a.price)` to it?

Comment: @gari this.item.productPrice is not the same with a.price.
this.item.productPrice =1.3
a.price =0.10
total in addition becomes =1.5 and if i remove it 1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TLDR(math behind)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) - You could use the [.toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) function:

```
var result = parseFloat('0.1') + parseFloat('1.3');
console.log(result.toFixed(1));​ // 1.4

var result = parseFloat('0.1') + parseFloat('1.3');
console.log(result);​ // 1.400000001
```